# SQL - joining two source columns to one target column

Tags: sql

I have two tables. The first table contains the code number, the second table contains the name corresponding to that code number. The first table has a source code number and a target code number. The second table contains both these code numbers in separate rows. So the tables look like this

Table1

```
|Source_code|Target_code|
|253        |568        |
```

Table2

```
|Code|Name |
|253 |John |
|568 |Steve|
```

I want a result like this:

```
|source_code|name |target_code|name |
|253        |John |568        |Steve|
```

I did this by joining both the tables twice in a single query, as follows:

```
select A.source_code, B.name, A.target_code, C.name
from table1 A
join table2 B on A.source_code = B.code
join table2 C on A.target_code = C.code
```

This doesn't look like the best way to handle this query. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Except you need to join on Table2's code not name :P

Comment: Thanks @xQbert. That was just a typo.
I somehow thought there would be a cleaner way to achieve this. Glad to know my query was not incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining to table 2 twice is the way to handle this.  Why?  because you have in table1 TWO foreign keys to Table2. Since tables should be joined on keys and you have two keys to one table, your solution is ***almost*** appropriate.

The only issue I see is ***you should be joining on table2's code*** not the names.

```
SELECT A.source_code, B.name, A.target_code, C.name
FROM table1 A
INNER JOIN table2 B 
  on A.source_code = B.Code
INNER JOIN table2 C 
  on A.target_code = C.code
```